# Perl Time, date conversion Error

Tags: perl, date, format

This is a perl script for sql data pulling each day for 100 days starting from Oct 1 and 
SQL is quite picky in date formats(yyyy-mm-dd), so I've written the script as follows.
However, at a specific day, on 2011-11-06, the time to date conversion is incorrect, and start and end date become the same.

```
$srt_date='2011-11-06'
$end_date='2011-11-06'
```

I don't know if this is perl error or something else.

```
use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle qw(:ora_types);
use Compress::Zlib;
use FileHandle;
use Date::Parse;
use Date::Format;

$st_day=str2time('2011-10-1');

@days=(0..100);

foreach $daynum (@days){
$dt1 = $st_day+3600*(24*$daynum);
$dt2 = $st_day+3600*(24*($daynum+1));
$srt_date = time2str("%d-%h-%Y", $dt1);
$end_date = time2str("%d-%h-%Y", $dt2);
print $srt_date, ',' ,$end_date, '\n';
my $sqlGetEid = "select x,y from z where DATETIME>='$srt_date' and DATETIME<'$end_date'";
}
```

Comment: Are you using [`HTTP::Date`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP::Date) for `str2time()` and `time2str()`?  If so, then `time2str()` only takes one argument.

Comment: 2011-11-06 was a daylight saving day transition so the day would have been 25-hours long.  You should compute the deltas with something like `DateTime`.

Comment: My best guess is that you are using `HTTP::Date` for `str2time`, and `Date::Format` for `time2str`. Is that correct? Even so I don't get a problem around 6-Nov-2011. Please show us more of your code.

Comment: I have added the code for the packages used. That was because of daylight saving time. Thanks. Then, what would be the easiest fix?

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't have a glitch at 6 November. If the problem is truly because of DST then you can get around it by removing the time fields in `$st_day` (setting the time  to midnight) as there is no confusion over the date at that time.

Comment: The problem surely relates to DST ending around that time, meaning one of the days has an amount of seconds other than 24*60*60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) handles the DST transitions correctly:

```
use strict; #ALWAYS!
use warnings; #ALWAYS!
use DateTime;

my $st_day = '2011-10-1';

my ($year, $month, $day) = split /-/, $st_day;

my $dt = DateTime->new(
    year => $year,
    month => $month,
    day => $day,
    time_zone => 'local',
);

my @days = 0..100;
foreach my $daynum (@days) {
    my $dt1 = $dt->ymd;
    my $dt2 = $dt->add(days => 1)->ymd;
    printf "%s,%s\n", $dt1, $dt2;
}
```

Comment: Great!. It works, but sql seems not understand DateTime object. I need to change $dt1 into string format.

Comment: @notilas - It doesn't have to understand a `DateTime` object, merely the output of the `ymd` method on a `DateTime` object.

Comment: my $sqlGetEid = "select x from y where DATETIME>='$dt1'; causes an error. DATETIME>=$dt1; also doesn't work. The error message is "DBD::Oracle::db prepare failed: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER"

Comment: You might have to do some typecasting to make Oracle recognize the date strings as dates.

Comment: Or just use [DateTime::Format::Oracle](http://p3rl.org/DateTime::Format::Oracle).

Comment: Use TO_DATE: select x from y where DATETIME>= TO_DATE('$dt1', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'); -- change the date format as needed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve exactly, but why bother executing 100 SQL statements when you can get away with something like:

```
SELECT trunc(datetime, 'DD') truncdate, x,y
FROM z WHERE datetime between '2011-10-01'
AND to_date('20111001', 'YYYYMMDD') + 99
```

Populate a hash with `truncdate` as key, and if your dates are ISO 8601, you'll get the same ordering by looping over the hash with a regular (`cmp`) sort.

**EDIT**: I'll clarify how you could do this:

```
my $sth = $mdbh->prepare("SELECT trunc(datetime, 'DD') truncdate, x,y
    FROM z WHERE datetime between '2011-10-01'
    AND to_date('20111001', 'YYYYMMDD') + 99
    ORDER BY truncdate");
$sth->execute();

my $lastdate = "";
my $fh;    

while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {

    # If new date, create new file
    if ($row->{truncdate} ne $lastdate) {
        close($fh) if $fh;
        open($fh, ">", "$row->{truncdate}.csv") or die "Unable to create file '$row->{truncdate}.csv': $!\n";
    }

    print $fh "$row->{x},$row->{y}\n";
    $lastdate = $row->{truncdate};
}
close($fh) if $fh;
```

Comment: Because the daily data is already very large, so I wanted to separate the data into 100 files.

Comment: @notilas: I probably wasn't clear enough about how you could separate the data into 100 chunks. I've added a code example now though.

Comment: The code looks very neat, but I got an error message "Use of uninitialized value in string ne at xxx" and "
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at xxx"